# SharePoint Custom Webservice

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, ws-security

I have a Custom SharePoint webservice for performing certain actions. User credentials are passed via Soap Header. The credentials reach the webservice without any problem.

**Issue:**
The following code returns "Unauthorized Error" if I did not make the webservice call with user credentials.

**WebService Method**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Test Credentials")]
[SoapDocumentMethod(Binding = "SPService")]
[SoapHeader("Authen")]
public string[] TestCredentials(string siteURL)
{
string[] credentials = new string[3];
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
    {
    using (SPWeb spW = site.OpenWeb())
        {
        credentials[0] = Authen.CallingUserName;
        credentials[1] = Authen.CallingUserPwd;
        credentials[2] = siteURL;                
        }
    }
return credentials;
}
```

**Client Code**

```
SPService.SPService spS = new SPService.SPService();//Webservice class
SPService.UserAuth ua = new SPService.UserAuth(); //Soap Header class
ua.CallingUserName = UserName; // User name
ua.CallingUserPwd = Password; // Password for the Username
spS.UserAuthValue = ua; // assigning the credential to the SoapHeader.

//System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(UName, pwd, Domain);
//spS.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UName, pwd, Domain);

string[] str = new string[3];
str = spS.TestCredentials(txt_URL.Text,"Shared Documents");
```

When the Network credential is commented out I get the `The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.` error. If the credential is used then the webservice returns the expected value.

Requirement of the Custom WebService is to use WS-Security to pass the Login credentials and use the same to login into the SharePoint site.

Some help would be useful. Kindly let me know if you need more detail regarding this.

Comment: Your code seems to be instantiating new credentials using those provided in the soap header, so it makes sense that if you don't provide them then you won't be authorised. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @JohnMc thanks for the quick response. Can i know which insantiation you are refering to. B'cos in the webservice method I have just returned the credentials back to the webclient which originally was sent from the client. When i use the network credentials for the calling webservice I am authorised to go in the SPWeb object and return the string array.

Comment: Sorry, the post I viewed originally looked different. It's clearer now. I would imagine that you're not even hitting the service when you comment out the credentials? Where is the service hosted? Have you enabled anonymous authentication? You will need that to access the service without credentials

Comment: @JohnMc, the credentials are not required when I don't use any SharePoint object inside the method. The error shows up only when I use SharePoint object with no network credentials. The Service is hosted in a local SharePoint server. Also the client application is in the same machine.

Comment: @JohnMc.. the SharePoint webservice is hosted in the local Sharepoint server. The webservice files are placed in the ISAPI folder of the server.

Answer (score 0):

The SPSite constructor will require authentication to intialise correctly as it is accessing Sharepoint. You can instantiate it using credentials you have constructed before hand in a similar manner to what is [described here](http://williamvanstrien.blogspot.ie/2011/11/programatically-open-spsite-using.html)